# Wordpress Content.php file

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm trying to remove the featured image at the top of this blog post wordpress template. The author did a great job, but just left the blog pretty bad.  I still need the featured images for thumbnails, however on this page it's a real mess.  I'd like the video to sit right under the banner up top.  I took out a bunch of stuff and messed it up.  I researched about using the class functions, another solution talked about editing the single.php file.  After looking through the single.php file, I concluded that everything that i wanted to remove appears to be located in a file called content.php.

so, here's the link: http://beautynetworkeffect.com/ground-zero-hong-kong-fashion-extravaganza-2015-fashion-one/

and here's the code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Javo_Directory
 * @since Javo Themes 1.0
 */

global $wp_query;
$javo_author    = new WP_User( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> class="row">
    <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
    <div class="featured-post">
        <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'javo_fr' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <header class="entry-header text-center">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', Array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                <div class="label-ribbon-row {f}">
                    <div class="label-info-ribbon-row-wrapper">
                        <div class="label-info-ribbon-row">
                            <div class="ribbons" id="ribbon-15">
                                <div class="ribbon-wrap">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="ribbon">
                                            <span class="ribbon-span">
                                                <?php echo get_the_date( 'M d Y'); ?>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.content -->
                                </div><!-- /.ribbon-wrap -->
                            </div><!-- /.ribbons -->
                        </div><!-- /.label-info-ribbon -->
                    </div><!-- /.ribbon-wrapper -->
                </div><!-- /.label-ribbon -->
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        </div><!-- col-md-4 -->

    </div>
    <div class="row entry-author-info-wrap">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 entry-author-image">
            <a>
                <div class="javo-thb" style="width:80px; height:80px; background-image:url('<?php echo apply_filters( 'javo_load_attach_image', $javo_author->avatar );?>');"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 entry-author-meta-wrap">
            <div class="entry-author-name"><?php echo $javo_author->display_name; ?></div>
            <div class="entry-author-social">
                <div class="entry-author-category">
                    <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
                    <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php if( comments_open() ) : ?>
                    <div class="pull-left" style="margin:0 10px;">
                        <span class="separator">/</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry-author-comment">
                        <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
                        <?php
                        comments_popup_link(
                            __( '0 Comment', 'javo_fr' )
                            , __( '1 Comment', 'javo_fr' )
                            , __( '% Comments', 'javo_fr' )
                        ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--row entry-author-info-wrap-->
    <div class="row entry-description-wrap">
        <div class="col-md-12 entry-description">
            <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <div class="single-post-meta row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 post-meta-infor">

                    </div> <!-- col-md-10 -->

                    <div class="col-md-2 text-right post-social">
                        <span class="javo-sns-wrap social-wrap">
                            <i class="sns-facebook" data-title="<?php the_title();?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                <a class="facebook javo-tooltip" title="<?php _e('Share Facebook', 'javo_fr');?>"></a>
                            </i>
                            <i class="sns-twitter" data-title="<?php the_title();?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                <a class="twitter javo-tooltip" title="<?php _e('Share Twitter', 'javo_fr');?>"></a>
                            </i>
                        </span>
                    </div> <!-- col-md-2-->
                </div> <!-- single-post-meta -->

            <?php else : ?>
                <h1 class="entry-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h1>
            <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
            <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
                <div class="entry-summary">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
            <?php else : ?>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php
                    if( is_category() )
                    {
                        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink(), javo_str_cut( get_the_excerpt(), 300));
                    }else{
                        the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'javo_fr' ) );
                    } ?>

                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'javo_fr' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- 12 Columns Close -->
    </div><!-- Row Close -->
    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <div class="inner-footer">
            <div class="inner-footer-more">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php _e( "more", 'javo_fr' ); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php //javo_drt_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( "<i class=\"fa fa-cog\"></i>" . __( 'Edit', 'javo_fr' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        <?php if ( is_singular() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && is_multi_author() ) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
            <div class="author-info">
                <div class="author-avatar">
                    <?php
                    /** This filter is documented in author.php */
                    $author_bio_avatar_size = apply_filters( 'javo_drt_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 );
                    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $author_bio_avatar_size );
                    ?>
                </div><!-- .author-avatar -->
                <div class="author-description">
                    <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'javo_fr' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                    <div class="author-link">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                            <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'javo_fr' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- .author-link -->
                </div><!-- .author-description -->
            </div><!-- .author-info -->
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->

</article><!-- #post -->
```

Answer (score 0):

To only remove the featured image you have to remove or comment the **"the_post_thumbnail"** line:

```
<?php // the_post_thumbnail('full', Array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
```

To remove the featured image and the date ribbon remove all those lines:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <header class="entry-header text-center">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', Array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
            <div class="label-ribbon-row {f}">
                <div class="label-info-ribbon-row-wrapper">
                    <div class="label-info-ribbon-row">
                        <div class="ribbons" id="ribbon-15">
                            <div class="ribbon-wrap">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="ribbon">
                                        <span class="ribbon-span">
                                            <?php echo get_the_date( 'M d Y'); ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.content -->
                            </div><!-- /.ribbon-wrap -->
                        </div><!-- /.ribbons -->
                    </div><!-- /.label-info-ribbon -->
                </div><!-- /.ribbon-wrapper -->
            </div><!-- /.label-ribbon -->
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    </div><!-- col-md-4 -->

</div>
```

Remember that all changes will be overwritten when you update the theme to a new version. A good option to avoid this is to create a Child Theme, the recommended way of modifying an existing theme. More information can be found at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Test it and let me know if you have any problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna add something here since it can be helpful for those who are willing to learn about Wordpress file Content.php.

This file is how wordpress generates post content on wordpress.

It can easily be understood by this code

```
if ( is_single() ) {
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
    } elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        the_title( '<h3 class="123123"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>' );
    } else {
        the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
    }
    ?>
```

It shows different content on the base of the page that is being requested.